# How does Facebook permissions review work on an existing Live site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My client has a website that uses FB to retrieve the current user's photos. This had been working for the last few years until recently, which I think is due to FB now requiring permissions to be reviewed by them first.

My client wants to hide the section of the site that uses FB until the issue is resolved, as it makes the site look broken.

My question is how can I submit the FB permissions to be reviewed when the section of the site that uses is hidden?  Surely this would be an issue for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the review description, you can add login data for the review team. Or you use a staging (sub)domain for the review. The Facebook review team is flexible, they will understand. And if you get problems with the review, you can ask in the official dev support group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/